# How to sort list on base of checkBoxes

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort array List of check boxes on base of check and unchecked status of controls checked check boxes will come first and unchecked checked boxes will come later in list. Then I shall add this to panel. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the CheckBoxes in a generic list and use its `Sort` method.

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = GetCheckBoxes();

// Unchecked CheckBoxes first
checkBoxes.Sort((firstCheckBox, secondCheckBox) => return firstCheckBox.Checked ? +1 : -1);

// Checked CheckBoxes first
checkBoxes.Sort((firstCheckBox, secondCheckBox) => return firstCheckBox.Checked ? -1 : +1);
```

Comment: I think `checkBox => return checkBox.Checked ? -1 : +1` (-1 & +1 are misplaced, this will sort unchecked then checked) question is to get all checked ordered before unchecked.

Comment: I am facing this error   ** Error 13 Delegate 'System.Comparison<System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox>' does not take '1' arguments **

Comment: Sorry, the Comparison delegate expects two parameters. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use a generic List of checkbox and sort it like below:

```
List<CheckBox> ar;
        ar.Sort(c => c.Checked);
```

Make sure to initialize the list ...